# R Exact match strings in two columns

Tags: r, string-matching, data-manipulation

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
Column1 = c('Elephant,Starship Enterprise,Cat','Random word','Word','Some more words, Even more words')
Column2=c('Rat,Starship Enterprise,Elephant','Ocean','No','more')
d1 = data.frame(Column1,Column2)
```

[image]

What I want to do is to look for and count the exact match of words in column 1 and column 2. Each column can have multiple words separated by a comma.

For example in row 1, we see there are two common words a) Starship Enterprise and b) Elephant. However, in row 4, even though the word **"more"** appears in both columns, the exact string (Some more words and Even more words) do not appear. The expected output would be something like this.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split columns on comma and count the intersection of words

```
mapply(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)), 
        strsplit(d1$Column1, ","), strsplit(d1$Column2, ","))
#[1] 2 0 0 0
```

---

Or a `tidyverse` way

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 %>%
  mutate(Common = map2_dbl(Column1, Column2, ~ 
      length(intersect(str_split(.x, ",")[[1]], str_split(.y, ",")[[1]]))))


#                           Column1                          Column2 Common
#1 Elephant,Starship Enterprise,Cat Rat,Starship Enterprise,Elephant      2
#2                      Random word                            Ocean      0
#3                             Word                               No      0
#4 Some more words, Even more words                             more      0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
v1 <- cSplit(setDT(d1, keep.rownames = TRUE), 2:3, ",", "long")[, 
    length(intersect(na.omit(Column1), na.omit(Column2))), rn]$V1
d1[, Common := v1][, rn := NULL][]
#                             Column1                          Column2 Common
#1: Elephant,Starship Enterprise,Cat Rat,Starship Enterprise,Elephant      2
#2:                      Random word                            Ocean      0
#3:                             Word                               No      0
#4: Some more words, Even more words                             more      0
```